# updating modifying codes in ASP.NET C# project

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to update an application with modified code in some files,So Is it enough to update the .dll file extension and the necessary files or Do i need to replace the whole project?

Comment: @user2232390 are you using IIS?

Comment: @SonerGönül I think It's a fairly decent question.  I pretty much know what he's asking, he's asking whether or not his website will work if he just updates 1 file, and it's only missing 1 detail that I can think of.  In fact, I think i'll +1 it

Comment: You want to just build  your project solutions.It's enough.

Answer (score 1):

You probably never need to replace the whole project. After you recompile, look at what DLLs were modified. You shouldn't need to replace *every* DLL in your bin, but you may need to replace each DLL that represents a project in your solution, depending on the dependencies of your solution.

So you will need to move over the DLLs that changed, as well as any other files that were modified (obviously excluding .cs, etc).

Though ideally, you will just use the "Publish" feature in Visual Studio, which automatically will copy over any (and only) necessary modified files. Doing it manually leaves too much room for error. Also (ideally) you will have a test server to publish with Debug settings so you can test, and then you publish with Release settings to your live server.

[How to: Deploy a Web Project Using One-Click Publish in Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465337.aspx)